# How to accelerate data access in PieCloudDB Database？

Tags: data-access, accelerate

Is there any way for PieCloudDB Database to accelerate data access? Does it have data cache? If yes, how to enable data cache in PieCloudDB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PieCloudDB Database uses the JANM storage engine to store data files in S3 object storage. Due to the impact of network bandwidth and object storage disk performance, data access can be accelerated by enabling caching and storing hot data on compute nodes.

To enable data cache, modify the following parameters.

```
pdbcli cluster  config --name pdb_janm_enable_disk_cache --value on -c ${pdbcc IP address}:${pdbcc port} -t tenant --cluster ID
```